# Expectation of log of shifted LogNormal random variable

Tags: distributions, expected-value, lognormal-distribution, moments

Suppose that we have a shifted log normal random variable,
$$Y = X + \beta, \qquad X \sim \log \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2), \qquad \beta > 0.$$

I'm struggling to obtain $\mathbb{E}[\log(Y)]$

Do I have a chance to get a closed form expression?

Comment: I know that $\log(X) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, however here, $Y$ is a shifted log-normal r.v. so we can't say that $\log(Y)$ is normal, right?

Comment: I imagine you could calculate this by integration which should work at least computationally and possibly an (approximate) analytical result can be fabricated. But before you do that nasty work... why do you wish to know E(log(Y)) instead of the much simpler E(Y)?

Comment: You definitely can't say that log(Y) is normal. It is not. It can be quite right skew or it can be nearly symmetric. I seriously doubt that you will get a closed form expression for it, unless you stretch the notion of closed form quite a bit.

Comment: Mathematica does not even give a closed-form expression in the case $\beta=1$, $\mu=0$, $\sigma=1$.